# rewrite rule nginx to add trailing slash with wordpress and exclude files with extension

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress

I have one installation with wordpress running on nginx with php-fpm. I want to redirect all uris without final slash / to a same uri with /, and i want to exclude all files with extensions.

I have this piece of code on my vhosts, but when I pont to www.myhost.com/readme.html nginx adds a traling slash, returning error, when the file exists, and occurs the same whith other file extensions.

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^/wp-admin")
{
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
rewrite ^([^.]*)$ /index.php;
```

The code i use before nginx, using apache on htaccess is this.

```
#Add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not a browser cache issue ? because actually your rewrite rules seems to work as expected.

Comment: Doesn`t seem a brower cache issue, I delete all the cache of firefox or chrome, and when i try to acces to www.mydomain.com/robots.txt the rewrite rule adds a slash at the end

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of the `[^.]*` in your first regex?  I'm thinking it should look something more like this:

```
rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```